# Scale factor in painting app is wrong

Tags: android, imageview

My goal is to move my finger over the screen to paint on a picture in an imageview `mImageView`. The picture there is resized to imageview-size to improve performance. Later I want to export this to the big image again, this is where `scaleFactor` comes in. When multiplying the real device coordinates with this factor, I should get where paint on the real images goes.

`path` is the uri to the underlying picture.

But it's always off, the areas I want to paint are not being painted in the final image. In general, `scaleFactor` is too big. Where is the problem? Or is this code right and the problem likely elsewhere?

`scaleFactor` is defined here for the first time.

```
private void displayFunction(Uri path) {   
    iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mImageView);
    int ivWidth = iv.getWidth();
    int ivHeight = iv.getHeight();

    Bitmap v = null;
    try {
        v = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), path);
    }
    catch (Exception vc)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (v == null) return;
    int originalWidth = v.getWidth(); 
    int originalHeight = v.getHeight(); 
    float rs = (float)originalWidth / (float)originalHeight;
    Bitmap bitmap2 = null;
    if (rs > 1)
        bitmap2 = getResizedBitmap(v,(int)((float)ivWidth / rs),ivWidth);
    else
        bitmap2 = getResizedBitmap(v,ivHeight,(int)((float)ivHeight * rs));
    scaleFactor = Math.max((float)originalWidth/(float)ivWidth, (float)originalHeight/(float)ivHeight);

    v = null;
    bmpTemp = clearPainting(bitmap2, Color.RED, 1, Paint.Style.STROKE);
    iv.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            iv.setImageBitmap(bmpTemp);
        }
    });
}
```

and

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/myCoordinatorLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="de.noahsofie.bildzuschneiden.MainActivity">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/html"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: You probably want to set the image view's matrix rather than scale the bitmap.  One causes you to make a new in memory bitmap using lots of resources on your CPU.  The other is done on the gpu.

Comment: Maybe. Yet how do I solve the problem itself?

Answer (score 0):

You want to display the big image only or paint on it as well? If the goal is to display the large bitmap only, you can draw the paths on the bitmap using canvas, and then scale the bitmap to any size that you want.